# Is there any way to monitor the stats of an Android application?

Tags: android, tool-recommend

Let's say I've installed an app on my Android phone and I'm using it. Is there any way I could monitor the various activity that the app is doing on the phone and gather stats around it?

I'm talking about something very similar to **"Process explorer"** that we have for Windows except that I need to gather the details from an Android app.

This is in the hopes of being able to test whether the application is working properly on the Android platform. If I see things like:

- CPU spikes,
- or, which files were accessed
- or a lot of battery consumption,
- or if I see it accessing the disk too frequently,

then those will all be defects against the app.

**Edit:**
**The solution has to be runnable on Android OS.** It should be something that I can install on Android so that it can trace out all files accessed by a particular process / CPU / memory / battery consumption. Just like how process explorer works on windows.

Answer (score 1):

What about reading the developer [manual](https://developer.android.com/studio/)? Always a great start...

To help you forward: [android profiling](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/) but honestly, just a little search and you likely would have found that yourself...

And before you call something defects: you should define what unexpected behaviour is first. A cpu spike is not a problem in itself, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for?

- In Android Studio select > Profiler (at the bottom of the Android Studio)

[image]

- Sessions and select + symbol afterwards the device (virtual device)

[image]

Comment: Not really. I think to run Android Studio I would need to be on windows? I meant something which we can install on the Android phone. Some kind of app that stays in the background and tracks the CPU usage to figure out which is the app that hogs CPU / memory / battery the most and traces all files used by any app.